# Trying to make RewriteCond case insensitive htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php
```

I am using the above code for removing the file extension of all the pages.
But, it is not Case Insensitive. Example: www.mysite.com/contact works fine, but www.mysite.com/Contact gives an error.

IMP: I have tried putting [NC] infront of both the code lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[nc] infront`? NC goes at the **END** of the line, e.g. `RewriteCond foo bar [NC]`.

Comment: Yeah, at the end I meant.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC]